# Regular expressions related, switch-statement emulation in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, switch-statement

**Desired outcome:**

I would like to have a parser function, which takes a string of "instructions".

This string will be chopped up using a `string.split(";")` and stripped of whitespace. I want to check each "chop" for a match against a bunch (10+) of regular expressions. Each expression also has capture groups defined values from which I would later use to "execute the command".

**The problem:**

I currently have a long and complex if, elseif, else statement, which is very undesirable, because it makes my code harder to manage and harder for others to read.

**Idea so far:**

Basically, I would like to use dictionaries to emulate a switch statement.  But I have very little experience with regular expressions, I was able to make the correct "expressions" to capture what I want in the "instructions". But I am very unfamiliar with the workings of the pythons regular expression package.

A step in the right direction would already be, a function, where given a single string, and a list, or dict of regular expressions, the function would return which of the reg-ex was matched.

**Example Code:** (excuse the indents:) )

```
class PreparedConstraintsCollection(ConstraintsCollectionABC):

not_pattern = re.compile("^not([-+]*[0-9]+)$")
ex_pattern = re.compile("^ex([-+]*[0-9]+)$")
more_pattern = re.compile("^>([-+]*[0-9]+)$")
less_pattern = re.compile("^<([-+]*[0-9]+)$")
interval_pattern = re.compile("^([-+]*[0-9]+)<x<([-+]*[0-9]+)$")

def parse_constraints_string(self, restriction_string: str) -> set:
    """
    The overly-complex function to parse the restriction control sequence strings

    Control Sequence        Meaning                     Explanation
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    +                       Positive only               Allow only positive values
    -                       Negative only               Allow only negative values
    notX                    Not X value                 Do not allow values X
    exX                     Must be X                   Only allow values X
    >X                      More then X                 Values must be more then X
    <X                      Less then X                 Values must be less then X
    M<x<N                   Interval M, N               Must be more then M but less then N

    :param restriction_string: a string with control sequences
    :return: return the gathered restriction instances, conserve only unique
    """
    gathered_constraints = set()

    for control_seq in restriction_string.split(";"):
        stripped = control_seq.strip().replace(" ", "")

        if stripped == "":
            continue

        elif stripped == "+":
            gathered_constraints.add(res_gallery.PositiveConstraint())

        elif stripped == "-":
            gathered_constraints.add(res_gallery.NegativeConstraint())

        elif self.not_pattern.match(stripped):

            searched = re.search(self.not_pattern, stripped)
            param = float(searched.group(1))
            gathered_constraints.add(res_gallery.NotExactValueConstraint(param))

        elif self.ex_pattern.match(stripped):

            searched = re.search(self.ex_pattern, stripped)
            param = float(searched.group(1))
            gathered_constraints.add(res_gallery.ExactValueConstraint(param))

        elif self.more_pattern.match(stripped):

            searched = re.search(self.more_pattern, stripped)
            param = float(searched.group(1))
            gathered_constraints.add(res_gallery.GreaterThanConstraint(param))

        elif self.less_pattern.match(stripped):

            searched = re.search(self.less_pattern, stripped)
            param = float(searched.group(1))
            gathered_constraints.add(res_gallery.LessThanConstraint(param))

        elif self.interval_pattern.match(stripped):

            searched = re.search(self.interval_pattern, stripped)
            param1, param2 = float(searched.group(1)), float(searched.group(2))
            gathered_constraints.add(res_gallery.IntervalConstraint(param1, param2))

        else:
            raise ValueError("Restriction string could not be parsed!")

    return gathered_constraints
```

Comment: It may be easier to assist you if you post some sample code and its expected output. Thank you for the great description of your problem though! It's rare to see new users put as much work into their questions as you have. Clear and concise :)

Comment: Posted the code, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility for your parser is to write a tokenizer that will create a nested list of all statements and the type found:

The first step is to create your grammar and tokenize your input string:

```
import re
import collections
token = collections.namedtuple('token', ['type', 'value'])
grammar = r'\+|\-|\bnot\b|\bex\b|\>|\<|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'
tokens = {'plus':'\+', 'minus':'\-', 'not':r'\bnot\b', 'ex':r'\bex\b', 'lt':'\<', 'gt':'\>', 'var':'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'}
sample_input = 'val1+val23; val1 < val3 < new_variable; ex val3;not secondvar;'
tokenized_grammar = [token([a for a, b in tokens.items() if re.findall(b, i)][0], i) for i in re.findall(grammar, sample_input)]
```

Now, `tokenized_grammar` stores a list of all tokenized grammar occurences in the text:

```
[token(type='var', value='val1'), token(type='plus', value='+'), token(type='var', value='val23'), token(type='var', value='val1'), token(type='lt', value='<'), token(type='var', value='val3'), token(type='lt', value='<'), token(type='var', value='new_variable'), token(type='var', value='ex'), token(type='var', value='val3'), token(type='var', value='not'), token(type='var', value='secondvar')]
```

Token types and values can be accessed as objects:

```
full_types = [(i.type, i.value) for i in tokenized_grammar]
```

Output:

```
[('var', 'val1'), ('plus', '+'), ('var', 'val23'), ('var', 'val1'), ('lt', '<'), ('var', 'val3'), ('lt', '<'), ('var', 'new_variable'), ('var', 'ex'), ('var', 'val3'), ('var', 'not'), ('var', 'secondvar')]
```

To implement the flow of a `switch`-`case` statement, you can create a dictionary, with each key being the type of a token, and the value being a class to store the corresponding value and methods to be added later:

```
class Plus:
   def __init__(self, storing):
     self.storing = storing
   def __repr__(self):
     return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.storing)
class Minus:
   def __init__(self, storing):
     self.storing = storing
   def __repr__(self):
     return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.storing)
...
```

Then, to create the dictionary:

```
tokens_objects = {'plus':Plus, 'minus':Minus, 'not':Not, 'ex':Ex, 'lt':Lt, 'gt':Lt, 'var':Variable}
```

Then, you can iterate over `tokenized_grammar`, and create a class object for each occurence:

```
for t in tokenized_grammar:
   t_obj = token_objects[t.type](t.value)
```

Comment: This looks awesome, thanks. So, if understand it correctly, the grammar defines all the capture groups, avoiding the need for chopping, catches all instances. Then, the tokens dict, defines the "capture groups", and extracts those values from the before caught groups, putting them in a dict, with token type an value being representative, creating a list of types and captured values. Which seems awesome since then I can just implement a second dict with keys as the token.types and values can be lambdas operating on the values.
Right?

Comment: @SirSteel that is correct. The regular expressions are grabbing all defined tokens and then storing them. You could use lambdas, however, I suggest using a dictionary to store the token type name and store a class for each token type. By using a class, you can create additional methods that can be quickly called by the object instance in the `for` loop. Please see my recent edit. I implemented the mentioned technique.

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much! :)